# How to load Python script into Jupyter Notebook without revealing code and making it available to all cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I'm trying to import a Python script as a module into one of my Notebooks, but the `import` or `import importlib` commands do not work in Jupyter Notebook like they do in a standard Python file and terminal.

I've come across the `%load` command but as far as I understand and have seen in my own Notebook, is that it only loads the contents of the script I'm trying to import into the current cell and is invisible to the other cells, and it also outputs the code in the script being imported for everyone to see.

I want to be able to load the script and make it available to all cells, as well as hiding the code for the purpose of encapsulation and also keeping the Notebook neat and tidy - only focusing on the code relevant to the topic of the Notebook. Is this possible?

Comment: Actually, `import` works in jupyter notebook. Why do you think they don't?

Comment: @Sraw Whoops, you're right. I was initially getting a `Name Error: name is not defined` error for a function I was trying to call but that was because I was calling the function by itself instead of doing `filename.myFunction()`